# How to find the solutions of the following equation?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let we have the following equation with the unknown $x$ 
$$\lfloor\ln(x+1)\rfloor - \lfloor\ln(x)\rfloor = 1$$ 
Where  $\lfloor x\rfloor$ means the integer part of $x$

Comment: Use formula for difference of logs.

Comment: Why did you enclose in square parentheses [ ] each one of those expressions? Why not merely write $\;\ln(x+1) - \ln x\;$ ? Does this mean anything special? And after this, what properties of logarithms you know?

Comment: It is [x] integer part of x, I think

Comment: Nice. The OP hasn't even addressed the comment, but someone already decided that he can read minds and edited the question...

Comment: but there is two answers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution set is a sequence of intervals.  For each positive integer $N$, we can construct an interval containing $e^N$.   Let

$$\epsilon = \ln\left(\frac{e^N}{e^N+1}\right).$$

Then the interval from $e^{N-\epsilon}$ to $e^N$ is a set of solutions.

You need

$$\ln(e^{N-\epsilon}+1)\geq N$$

and solving this inequality gives the value for $\epsilon.$